# Logging POST data in NGINX and avoiding unnecessary parameters

Tags: post, nginx, logging

I want to log POST data in NGINX and am using $request_body to do the same.

But there are POST fields that I don't want to log (like password, email etc). Is it possible to parse the post data OR asynchronously send data to a PHP/RUBY or any other script so that i can parse the POST data there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved this by using [Nginx LUA module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule). and then by calling `ngx.req.get_post_args()` in the lua script, i was able to get the post content in the form of a table (LUA's arrays). Hence parsing this in lua itself removing unnecessary parameters and logging it solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to access post parameters directly with default modules, but you could try to make little hack , to achieve this. This is the example:

```
location /forPost { 
    try_files /logger.php $uri;
}
```

The script should always return 404 status, this is exampe:

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['data']) ) {
       logger($_POST['data']);
   }
   header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
   header("Status: 404 Not Found")
   die();
?>
```